# Why argc of main() function is at ESP+4 and not ESP+0?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

According to many tutorials on the internet, it is said that you can find command line arguments structured following way:

[image: table]

However, after some time spend of testing my Assembly code written for NASM I found out that value at ESP is some number, like:

```
-144807325
```

Actual argument count is stored 4 bytes farther, at ESP+4.

Any idea what is stored at ESP+0? And why is that different from many articles teaching Assembly?

Below you can find my code to reproduce this problem:

```
section .data
    msg db  "%d", 0xA

section .text
    global main
    extern printf

main:
    push dword [esp + 0] ; or [esp + 4]
    push msg
    call printf
    pop eax
    pop eax
    mov eax, 0
    ret
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tutorials you mention talk about initial process startup. `main` is not run at that point, it is called later by the C startup code according to standard C calling convention. As such, at `[esp]` you have the return address. See also [Linux x86 Program Start Up or - How the heck do we get to main()? by Patrick Horgan](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html)

Comment: If frame pointers are being used, then main starts with the sequence 
| push ebp | mov ebp,esp |, in which case the pointer to the first argument is at ebp+8.